# C# calling unmanaged code: "Cannot convert from 'CustomClass' to 'ref System.IntPtr'"

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I am writing wrapper functions for a c++ library in c#.
My function in c++ takes two pointers as arguments of which it changes the content one of them points to (`foo`).
So in c# I need to pass this as a `ref` right?
I have:

C++:

```
ErrorCode MyFunction(void* dev, void* foo);
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern ExceptionClass.ErrorCode MyFunction(IntPtr dev, ref IntPtr foo);
```

When I call the function in C# like this

```
public void CallFunction(DevClass dev, FooClass foo)
{
  MyFunction(dev, ref foo);
}
```

I get the Error

`Error 3   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref FooClass' to 'ref System.IntPtr'`

Comment: If `DevClass` and `FooClass` are structs, then change the declaration to `(ref DevClass dev, ref FooClass foo)`. If they are classes, then how are you going to handle managed classes on the unmanaged side?

Comment: I could be wrong here but as the error suggest you are attenmpting to convert a pointer to FooClass. Try to create a IntPtr variable and use that to call MyFunction

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you have to put a *ref* there for the 2nd parameter *foo*

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The IntPtr type can be used by languages that support pointers, and as
>   a common means of referring to data between languages that do and do
>   not support pointers.

So an IntPtr is like a pointer, you can modify the data it points to.

Comment: If I remove it I get the same error message. Just without the `ref` in `ref FooClass`

Comment: Then what's the diff between the DevClass and the FooClass?

Comment: the compile error is because you try to convert an object to the IntPtr.